# How can get the current time of a video to set it in textview..?

Tags: android

i had tried this:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        videoview.getCurrentPosition;
    }
},0,1000);
```

but it does not work(it crashes).

it says:

"cant create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare"  =/

Comment: Don't just tell us it crashes.  Tell us what the crash log says.

Comment: Edited , thanks  , it says:

"cant create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare"

Comment: You're trying to create a Handler on a thread that can't support one.  If you meant to create a Handler for the main thread, create it on the main thread.

Comment: ok i did that(see the answer below please  =D ) but now my code works , as maximum , 1 time per second  =/ , i need it each 1/4 second.  =/

Comment: You're porting the times on a 1 second delay. Put it on whatever delay you actually want

Comment: i changed 1000 to 100 , and it only works 1 time per second    =S

Comment: Ok Gabe , it works , i was using Toast as my "function" , and , according what i can see , by defect , it works only(the Toast) 1 time per second , i changed to a setText and it runs normal , thanks for your time.  

(english is not my native lenguage , apologizes if there are wrong words  =)    )

Answer (score 0):

Please , post your answer if you have one , i found this way.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

@Override
public void run() {

    handler.post( new Runneable(){

      public void run (){

        //Your function  =D

       }

    });
}
},0,1000);
```